# Different number of columns based on device

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to create different number of columns based on the device.

For example: on mobile I want `2-col` layout and on desktop `4-col` layout etc...

I've tried messing around with `minmax()` , but couldn't make it happen the way I want, any advice for achieving this with `minmax()`.

would someone have the answer?

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="col">1</div>
  <div class="col">2</div>
  <div class="col">3</div>
  <div class="col">4</div>
  <div class="col">5</div>
  <div class="col">6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: use media query and define your columns list grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr) or grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr)

Comment: Is there a particular reason that make you not use Bootstrap (or any other CSS framework)? It already contain a pretty solid grid system.

Comment: @Dexter0015 You are right, but for two reason one is for better understanding, second Im using a `wp` theme that I want to modify that don't really user bootstrap

Comment: @Satif thanks, I'v achieved this with the media query's, just wanted to know if there is a option doing this with minmax. appreciate

Comment: @Osh make sense!

Comment: Voting to close as OP already has `media-queries` (based on comment), which is the way to solve this. `minmax` would still need to be set with different values in the `media-query`

Comment: @Osh it's better to use `media` in `css` to mange the screen size and set col
you can check [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com) style gide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how you want to layout your Grid regardless you will have to use **Media Queries** and define each of your columns.

Example:

`div class="col one">1</div>`

`div class="col two">2</div>`

**This is the *mobile* lay out**

```
   .wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 1em;
    grid-template-areas:
     "header"
     "sidebar"
     "content"
     "sidebar2"
     "footer"
    }
```

**This is the *Tablet* lay out**

```
    @media only screen and (min-width: 500px)  {
    .wrapper {

        grid-template-columns: 20% auto;
        grid-template-areas:
    "header   header"
        "sidebar  content"
        "sidebar2 sidebar2"
        "footer   footer";
    }
    }
```

**This is the *desktop* lay out**

```
    @media only screen and (min-width: 600px)   {
        .wrapper {
      grid-gap: 20px;
            grid-template-columns: 120px auto 120px;
            grid-template-areas:
      "header  header  header"
            "sidebar content sidebar2"
            "footer  footer  footer";
            max-width: 600px;
        }
    }
```

Here is an example of using css grid with Media Queries. In this example, `box` is followed with a unique `div` class name. You can use that class name to layout the grid.

```css
body {
  margin: 40px;
}

.sidebar {
        grid-area: sidebar;
    }

    .sidebar2 {
        grid-area: sidebar2;
    }

    .content {
        grid-area: content;
    }

    .header {
        grid-area: header;
    }

    .footer {
        grid-area: footer;
    }

    .wrapper {
        background-color: #fff;
        color: #444;
    }

  .wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 1em;
    grid-template-areas:
     "header"
     "sidebar"
     "content"
     "sidebar2"
     "footer"
  }

    @media only screen and (min-width: 500px)  {
    .wrapper {

        grid-template-columns: 20% auto;
        grid-template-areas:
    "header   header"
        "sidebar  content"
        "sidebar2 sidebar2"
        "footer   footer";
    }
    }

    @media only screen and (min-width: 600px)   {
        .wrapper {
      grid-gap: 20px;
            grid-template-columns: 120px auto 120px;
            grid-template-areas:
      "header  header  header"
            "sidebar content sidebar2"
            "footer  footer  footer";
            max-width: 600px;
        }
    }

.box {
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 150%; 
}

.header,
.footer {
  background-color: #999;
}

.sidebar2 {
  background-color: #ccc;
  color: #444;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box header">Header</div>
  <div class="box sidebar">Sidebar</div>
  <div class="box sidebar2">Sidebar 2</div>
  <div class="box content">Content
    <br /> More content than we had before so this column is now quite tall.</div>
  <div class="box footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cheers for the in depth answer I understand unless I need a generic responsive solution media queries is the way to go, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would use [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/)

basic idea is

- lg is used for large windows (desktop)
- md is used for medium windows (desktop)
- xm is used for small windows (i.e phone / tablets)
- xs is used for extra small windows (i.e phone)
- you can also hide any of these layouts

  ```
  <div id="container">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">1</div>
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">2</div>
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">3</div>
     <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">4</div>
     <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">5</div>
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">6</div>
  </div>
  ```